# How can I keep things aligned in an adaptive layout

Tags: css, css-position, adaptive-layout

I'm building an adaptive design using CSS and I'm wondering how I can keep things nicely aligned. Two examples so far: my page: http://www.spabc.com/drupal/ now, I would like to keep the `check-rates_btn` aligned with the `titleimg` as the browser window resizes but due to the image being set a `width` of `95%`, I can't really keep things aligned. I'd also like to keep the `logo` nicely aligned with the image i.e.  where it hangs over `titleimg`, I want to keep the room that it hangs over = to the distance on the right side to the border of the `titleimg`. I tried to depict what I mean here: The distances depicted with red lines should stay equal. How do I do this?[image]

Comment: There's many ways, you just need to  learn some basic HTML & CSS.
You can put the image in a container and then put the logo in the same container and adjust the position.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to adjust the styles for `check-rates_btn` and `titleimg` accordingly using [CSS Media Queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries).

Unfortunately, you are using Drupal and have too many cached CSS files for me to look through, but the ones I did look at (`layout.css` and `system.theme.css`) only had a few specific media queries that were not altering these classes.

Hope this helps.

Comment: so you're saying I basically need to "re-adjust" my layout as the screen shrinks in different `@media` "steps". Is that really true? `layout.css` and `style.css` contain the definitions for the above elements.

Comment: @cerr, yes, that is correct.  Based on the size of the screen, you can assign different styles to the elements to get them to react the way you want them to.  layout.css has a few media queries in there already that you can use as an example.